# Install4j error message- The version of the bundled JRE is too high. It should be at most 1.6

Tags: java, install4j

I am using install4j version 5.1.14 and have previously successfully put together a windows installer for a java 6 application with a bundled  6 jvm. We have now upgraded the application to java 8 (I ran and built the app jar file in netbeans under java 8). I have bundled java windows-amd64-1.8.0_20 in the install4j installer project setup.

When I run the install4j builder I get this error message:

[WARNING] The version of the bundled JRE is too high. It should be at most 1.6!

What has gone wrong?

Comment: Were you able to solve this ? If yes, can you please tell how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Java maximum version on the "General Settings->Java version step". It should be set to 1.8.